# Angular - Generate dynamic fill-in-the-blank and multiple-choices exercises/questions

Tags: angular

A few years ago, I created a website in which it is possible to create question/answer, fill-in-the-blank or multiple choice exercises/questions. For the last two types of questions, everything is saved in a database in text format, as follow :

```
The rabbit eats !!!12345!!! and lives in a !!!45678!!!.
```

Here, the pattern !!!nnnnn!!! represents a "question", either text input (fill-in-the-blank) or a dropdown with multiple choices. This way, I can insert them anywhere in a text and it gives quite dynamic exercises.

What I was doing until now was that I was generating HTML at the server level with Django and returning the corresponding input or dropdown directly, which would give here for the example :

```
<p>
    The rabbit eats 
        <select id="12345">
            <option value="carrot">carrot</option>
            <option value="banana">banana</option>
        </select>
    and lives in a <input type="text" id="45678">.
</p>
```

Then every values given by the user are corrected via an AJAX request and that's it (the correct values are stored in the db).

At the moment, I'd like to port the site to Angular and I'm wondering how to do it. I could go with [innerHTML] and the "safeHtml" pipe, but I doubt that's the way to go (is it ?). If anyone can advise me on the way forward, that would be nice, right now I can't see. Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in Angular before, though I did not do "inline" questions in the middle of a paragraph - I had question text, followed by an answer, which, as in your scenario, could have different HTML control types.

But, I think that the solution for your scenario could be similar.
Here's my suggestion:

On the back-end, for each question, store a list of items to be displayed.
Each item in the list could be a chunk of text or "answer data" of various types, e.g. simple text input with id, select with id and option data, etc, but as data, not as HTML.

On the client side, make an API call to the back-end to get JSON containing the list of question data.

Then, render components for each of the chunks - spans or divs for the paragraph text, inputs of type 'text' for the simple text, selects for the select data with options, etc.

As far as how to render these, there's basically two choices:

1. loop through the list of 'chunks' and inside the loop, have a block for each of the chunk types, with *ngIf on each to match the type.

For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let chunk of chunks">
  <span *ngIf="chunk.type === 'para-text'" id="chunk.id">{{ chunk.text }}</span>
  <input type="text" *ngIf="chunk.type === 'text-input'" id="chunk.id">
  <select *ngIf="chunk.type === 'select' id="chunk.id">
   <option *ngFor="let opt of chunk.options" value="opt.value">{{opt.label}}</option>
  <select>
</div>
```

2, The more elegant, but less immediately obvious way is to use dynamic components. For more info on that, see https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The fact is, I cannot modify how the questions are stored in the DB actually. The final user used a WYSIWYG editor, so there is a lot of HTML in the data. What I will do is split the data before rendering it, so I will have these chunks, easy to use as you wrote it. Very good idea. I will then create a <question> component, that will take the id as @input handle the *ngIf part. Thanks again !